# How to get all photos taken at a place with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, facebook-fql, photos

I am building a web site for an event venue. I want to use Facebook API to get the photos taken at the venue by other people.

I can do a graph search on Facebook for "photos taken at place-x" and it works fine. It shows all photos taken at the venue location, not limited to my friends.

However I have spent many hours scouring through Graph Search API and FQL trying to do the same within the API Explorer with no success.

The closest I've come is to get the location_post with the place_id, but they are only limited to my friends, which doesn't make sense in this case.

Anyone done this before? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with Facebook's Public Feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

Though it says:

*"Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot apply to use the API at this time."*

meaning it's not available for all developers. I've been trying to find a way to apply with no success.